# PHP/Amazon S3: Query string authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I have been using the `Zend_Service_Amazon_S3` library to access Amazon S3, but have been unable to find anything that correctly deals with generating the secure access URLs.

My issue is that I have multiple objects stored in my bucket with an ACL permission of access to owner only. I need to be able to create URLs that allow timed access. However, [the documentation for Amazon S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/S3_QSAuth.html) is very brief on the subject.

Could someone elaborate, or provide a link to something that explains how I might achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation located in the [authenticating REST requests](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html) section deals with generating the signature required for the URLs. It would be a simple case of implementing a PHP function that can generate this type of signature.

Comment: +1 - Thanks, this just saved me a bunch of Google searching! I love StackOverflow :-)